# Como obtener el dato de un atributo name dentro de un input dentro de un while(fetch_array)

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysqli

tengo el siguiente código de un formulario de busqueda:

```
<form role="form" method="POST">
        <div class="row busqueda">
            <div class="input-field col s12 mb-5">
                <input id="busqueda" name="busqueda" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="busqueda">Introduce la palabra clave para buscar</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center mt-3 mb-5">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large mx-auto">Buscar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

que tiene como backend en php el siguiente código:

```
<?php include '../conexion.php';

$tbl_name = "usuarios_web";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE 
num_clienteLIKE'%$_POST[busqueda]%'
OR usuario COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$_POST[busqueda]%'
OR email COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$_POST[busqueda]%'
OR verificacion COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$_POST[busqueda]%'
";

$resConsulta = $conexion ->query($consulta);

 echo '<tr  class="theadPhp">
    <th>Número de Cliente</th>
    <th>Usuario</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Verificación</th>
</tr>';
while ($registroConsulta = $resConsulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){        
echo ' <style>         
      input::placeholder{
        color:black;
      }
      #inputTabUsuarios{
          width:40%;
          border: 0;
      }
    .table td, .table th{
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
  </style>
      <tr>
        <td>'.$registroConsulta['num_cliente'].'</td>
        <td>'.$registroConsulta['usuario'].'</td>
        <td>'.$registroConsulta['email'].'</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="inputTabUsuarios" class="validate2" 
 value="' .htmlspecialchars($registroConsulta['verificacion']).'" 
 placeholder="" name="ver"/></td>
      </tr>'; 

     }

  }
 mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Este documento php se llama busquedaUsuario.php y lo incluyo con un include en la página del buscador.
Si os fijáis dentro de la tabla que genera el while hay un input

```
<td><input type="text" id="inputTabUsuarios" class="validate2" value="' 
.htmlspecialchars($registroConsulta['verificacion']).'" placeholder="" 
name="ver"/></td>
```

del cual tengo el siguiente formulario en el mismo documento que el anterior formulario de búsqueda:

```
<form id="form_enviar" action="inputTablaPopys.php" method="post">
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
 <?php 
  include 'busquedaUsuario.php'
  ?>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

para el cual uso el siguiente script con ajax y jquery para poder usar la tecla enter en el input

```
<script>

 $('.validate2').keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   if(keycode == '13'){
    var validate = $('.validate2').val();
    $.post('inputTabla.php', {validate:validate}, function(data){
        if (data == "Insertado"){
            alert("Datos Insertados");
        }else if (data=="Actualizado"){
            alert("Datos Actualizados");
        }else if(data=="Error"){
            alert("Error en consulta");
        }
    });
   }

});

</script>
```

este script utiliza otro documento php que actualiza o introduce datos en la base de datos mysqli:

```
<?php

set_error_handler('errorHandler');

 function errorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
 echo 'Into '.__FUNCTION__.'() at line '.__LINE__.
 "\n\n---ERRNO---\n". print_r( $errno, true).
 "\n\n---ERRSTR---\n". print_r( $errstr, true).
 "\n\n---ERRFILE---\n". print_r( $errfile, true).
 "\n\n---ERRLINE---\n". print_r( $errline, true).
 "\n\n---ERRCONTEXT---\n".print_r( $errcontext, true).
 "\n\nBacktrace of errorHandler()\n".
 print_r( debug_backtrace(), true);
}

 include '../conexion.php';

 header('Content-type: application/json');


 $buscar ="SELECT verificacion FROM $tbl_name ";
 $result = $conexion->query($buscar);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if($count== 0){

  $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios_web (verificacion)
       VALUES ('$_POST[ver]')";

  if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {

    return print(json_encode('Insertado'));

  }
 }
   else if ($count== 1){
     $query2 = "UPDATE TABLE usuarios_web SET verificacion = '$_POST[ver]' 
   WHERE verificacion = '$_POST[ver]'";

      if ($conexion->query($query2) === TRUE) {

    return print(json_encode('Actualizado'));

  }else{
    return print(json_encode('Error'));

   }

 }
?>
```

El caso es que llevo unos días intentando conseguir que funcione pero no lo consigo, me salían varios errores de Undefined index : var, que es el name del input y ahora sale una página en blanco. Lo que quiero hacer está más o menos claro, quiero que el input de esa tabla dentro del formulario que tiene el while me actualize o me inserte los datos en la tabla. Si pudierais ayudarme me vendría muy bien porque no encuentro la solución a poder acceder a ese name del input dentro del array

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es generar un `form` por cada input de esta forma solo mandas los POST que te interesan.

## Ejemplo modificado con `form` para cada input:

**En la zona de creación del formulario:**

*Elimina el form de esta parte*

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
 <?php 
  include 'busquedaUsuario.php'
  ?>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**En la zona del input:**

*Colocas el Form en cada vuelta del While*

```
<?php include '../conexion.php';

$tbl_name = "usuarios_web";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE 
num_clienteLIKE'%$_POST[busqueda]%'
OR usuario COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$_POST[busqueda]%'
OR email COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$_POST[busqueda]%'
OR verificacion COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$_POST[busqueda]%'
";

$resConsulta = $conexion ->query($consulta);

 echo '<tr  class="theadPhp">
    <th>Número de Cliente</th>
    <th>Usuario</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Verificación</th>
</tr>';
while ($registroConsulta = $resConsulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){        
echo ' <style>         
      input::placeholder{
        color:black;
      }
      #inputTabUsuarios{
          width:40%;
          border: 0;
      }
    .table td, .table th{
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
  </style>
      <tr>
        <td>'.$registroConsulta['num_cliente'].'</td>
        <td>'.$registroConsulta['usuario'].'</td>
        <td>'.$registroConsulta['email'].'</td>
        <td>
<form id="form_enviar" action="inputTablaPopys.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="inputTabUsuarios" class="validate2" 
 value="' .htmlspecialchars($registroConsulta['verificacion']).'" 
 placeholder="" name="ver"/>
</form>
</td>
      </tr>'; 

     }

  }
 mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

De esta forma el `$.post('inputTabla.php', {validate:validate}, function(data){ ...` no se activa. Y `inputTablaPopys.php` recibe el POST .

---

## Simulación para testar esta opción

Esta es la simulación que he creado...

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <form id="form_enviar" action="inputTablaPopys.php" method="post">
                     <input type="text" id="inputTabUsuarios" 
                            class="validate2" value="verificacion1" placeholder=""
                            name="ver"/>
                  </form>
              </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
              <td>
                  <form id="form_enviar" action="inputTablaPopys.php" method="post">
                      <input type="text" id="inputTabUsuarios" 
                              class="validate2" value="verificacion2" 
                              placeholder=""
                              name="ver"/>
                  </form>
              </td>
          </tr>



          <tr>
              <td>
                  <form id="form_enviar" action="inputTablaPopys.php" method="post">
                       <input type="text" id="inputTabUsuarios" 
                               class="validate2" 
                               value="verificacion3" placeholder=""
                               name="ver"/>
                  </form>
              </td>
          </tr>

        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

En el **inputTablaPopys.php** ...

```
<?php

set_error_handler('errorHandler');

 function errorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
 echo 'Into '.__FUNCTION__.'() at line '.__LINE__.
 "\n\n---ERRNO---\n". print_r( $errno, true).
 "\n\n---ERRSTR---\n". print_r( $errstr, true).
 "\n\n---ERRFILE---\n". print_r( $errfile, true).
 "\n\n---ERRLINE---\n". print_r( $errline, true).
 "\n\n---ERRCONTEXT---\n".print_r( $errcontext, true).
 "\n\nBacktrace of errorHandler()\n".
 var_dump( debug_backtrace(), true);
}




    return var_dump(json_encode($_POST['ver']));


?>
```

---

**Vigila que en tu script tienes esto...**

Veo un error en ... `$_POST[ver]` debería estar entre comillas `$_POST["ver"]`